# Should solr be included with a web app, or seperate

Tags: java, tomcat, solr

I want to add search capabilities to my web application with solr.
Deploying solr with the WAR provided with the SOLR distribution is very simple and straight forward, but I'm wondering if it makes sense to do so?

Should solr be deployed as a seperate WAR, or integrated in the web application?

To summerise I have few questions:

- Shold SOLR be deployed as a seperate WAR or integrated in the application.
- In case it should be integrated in the application, how can i do so with the latest SOLR version? all of the resources I've found for this refer to older versions and rely on depreceated classes.
- In case it should be deployed seperatly, how should I approach testing my application? as SOLR would have to be deployed seperatly it would make testing very clumsy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not attempt to deploy Solr as a WAR.

From the documentation...

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Major+Changes+from+Solr+4+to+Solr+5

> Beginning with Solr 5.0, Solr is no longer distributed as a "war" (Web Application Archive) suitable for deployment in any Servlet Container.  Solr is now distributed as a stand alone java server application, including start and stop scripts for use on Unix and MS-Windows platforms...
>
> ...
>
> Internally, Solr is still implemented via Servlet APIs and is powered by Jetty -- but this is simply an implementation detail.  Deployment as a "webapp" to other Servlet Containers (or other instances of Jetty) is not supported, and may not work in future 5.x versions of Solr when additional changes are likely to be made to Solr internally to leverage custom networking stack features.

Comment: This answer does not address the question of deploying solr standalone versus embedding solr into a web-app. Its merely talking about deploying solr standalone, which up to version 5 could be done using the provided solr.war. From version 5 on no solr.war is provided any more but solr is distributed as stand alone java server app based on an internal Jetty

Answer (score 0):

I would deploy Solr separately:

- You can (now or later) separate Solr physically from your web-app, i.e. put Solr and your web-app on different machines to separate resource utilization (CPU, Memory, ...)
- You can scale Solr horizontally (now or later)
- Solr and your webapp run in different JVMs and therefore you separate Memory Management and Garbage Collection
- You can access Solr from a different application